# creating a pandas extension on a geopandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, extension-methods, geopandas

I am working to create way to easily perform a bunch of disciplinary-specific computations on geospatial data. I know that Pandas has an extension API (`@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("name")`), and I know that geopandas is, under the hood, a Pandas extension. Thus, I am wondering if I can use the Pandas extension API on a geopandas object:

```
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("MyGPDext")
class GeoExtender:
    def __init__(self, geopandas_obj):
        self._obj = geopandas_obj

    def offcenter(self):
        return self._obj.geometry.centroid() + [15, 20] # as an arbitrary example of needing
                                                        # a geopandas method within my method
```

Comment: It seems like you've written this code already. Does it work?

Comment: Thanks @PaulH! I was so busy wondering if it would work to layer an extension on an extension that I failed to notice I'd written enough code that I could try it and see. A few syntax issues (can't add a list to a geometry array) but otherwise it looks to be working so far.